# Is there a way to call my function based on the amount of time the user inputed

Tags: javascript

I am writing a program for a quote generator and I need some help getting my quote to generator a set number of times depending on what the user input.

I've tried to iterate and pus the result into an array but it only pushes the same result for e.g 4 times

```
//Flowers quotes
'use strict';

const randomFlowersQuote = () => {

    const fragBeginning = ['These are very beautiful ', 'I like looking at ', ' Today We saw some new ', 'There a nice '];
    const fragMiddle = ['flower pots', 'hibiscuss trees', 'red roses', 'lily flowers', 'rare flowers'];

    const fragEnd = [' i would love to buy one', ' they are very nice', ' they are so breathtaking', ' in the shop'];

    //Random generated quotes

    const fragBeginningRandom = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fragBeginning.length)];
    const fragMiddelRandom = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fragMiddle.length)];
    const fragEndRandom = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fragBeginning.length)];
    const fullQuote = [fragBeginning[fragBeginningRandom] + fragMiddle[fragMiddelRandom] + fragEnd[fragEndRandom]];

    return fullQuote;
}

console.log(randomFlowersQuote());
```

I expect when the user enters 3 it calls the function 3 times.

Comment: Post what you've tried with iteration. That should be doing what you want.

Comment: Where does the user input come in?

Comment: @Snukus I created another function for testing to push the results into an array but it only gives me 1 output with the others showing undefined

Comment: function randomGen() {
        var quoteArr = []
        if (quoteArr.length < 3) {
            let i = 0;
            while (i < 5) {
                const fullQuote = [fragBeginning[fragBeginningRandom] + fragMiddle[fragMiddelRandom] + fragEnd[fragEndRandom]];
                quoteArr.push(fullQuote[i]);
                i++
                // console.log(quoteArr[i]);
            } //if statement
            console.log(quoteArr);
        }
    }

Comment: @SteveT I haven't set that up as yet, I was only trying to get it to work and output in the console before I add that feature

Comment: The program is basically to get random quotes from 3 fragments. The allows the user to select how many they want to see between 1 - 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have one solution,
I modified your code and try to run this, and this gives me output as you required. According to me :)

```
const fragBeginning = ['These are very beautiful ', 'I like looking at ', ' Today We saw some new ', 'There a nice '];
const fragMiddle = ['flower pots', 'hibiscuss trees', 'red roses', 'lily flowers', 'rare flowers'];

const fragEnd = [' i would love to buy one', ' they are very nice', ' they are so breathtaking', ' in the shop'];





    function RandomGeneratedQuotes(number)
    {   
       var quotes = [];
       for(var i = 0; i < number; i++){
            const fragBeginningRandom = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fragBeginning.length)];
            const fragMiddelRandom = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fragMiddle.length)];
            const fragEndRandom = [Math.floor(Math.random() * fragBeginning.length)];
            const fullQuote = [fragBeginning[fragBeginningRandom] + fragMiddle[fragMiddelRandom] + fragEnd[fragEndRandom]];
            quotes.push(fullQuote);
        } return quotes;
    }
```

on function call output will be:

```
console.log(RandomGeneratedQuotes(3))
VM431:1 
(3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
0: [" Today We saw some new rare flowers i would love to buy one"]
1: ["These are very beautiful flower pots i would love to buy one"]
2: [" Today We saw some new rare flowers in the shop"]
```

This should work for you flawless

Comment: This is going to return an array of arrays. If you want it to be an array of strings, remove the brackets from around fullQuote.

Comment: Thank you guys, for my understanding and progress, where was I going wrong?  

Thanks, Again

Comment: @VallisWeekes, if you think your problem is solved then please upvote the right answer, SO that next visitor can focus on the right result, and let me know if still have doubts

Comment: @DupinderSingh I think I've done it. it's only my 2nd time posting on here. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @DupinderSingh is there a way to restrict the number they as I only want maximum 5 quotes outputted.